# how can i get my nodejs file to recongnice when a change has been made to a json file?

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a nodejs program, in the program I need to be able to check a variable inside a JSON file that will be switched via a different program. I started working on an if statement to figure it out, I soon found out that nodejs doesn't like it when i go around switching variables after the code has been ran. I ran a code that looked a little like this:

```
"wait for event"{
"code once event happens"
var jsonfile = require('./jsonfile.json')
console.log(jsonfile.variable)}
```

I would trigger the event, change the json manually then trigger it again
the output would look like this

```
true
true
```

meaning that it would NOT read the json file after i change it

I tried to force it to 're require' the JSON file in the code above but that hasn't worked, Ive tried running it in a fresh nodejs script to see if it was because of a statement it could possibly be inside the code looked like this

```
while (true){
var file = require('file.json')
console.log(file.variable)}
```

i would change the variable and the output would keep outputting `true` or `false`

that didnt work.

Comment: Instead of using require, have you tried reading the json file with the native file system, like [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback)? Or a library like [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra)?

Comment: no, i havent. ill try

Answer (score 0):

Geshode wrote a comment that said:
`Instead of using require, have you tried reading the json file with the native file system, like fs.readFile? Or a library like fs-extra?`

that worked
i put it as an answer so other people can see it,
if you need heres some code samples

to read a json file:

```
fs.readFile('pathtojson', 'utf8', function(err, data){
    let student = JSON.parse(data);
    // Display the file content
    console.log(student.avariableinfile);
  })
```

if edited correctly should output a variable inside of your json file

to read WITHOUT making it a json object

```
fs.readFile('pathtofile', 'utf8', function(err, data){
    // Display the file content
    console.log(data);
  });
```

note: the only differences between these samples is the second one dosnt make it into a json file it will do the same thing if you replace `data` in `console.log(data)` to `student.varable` and add `JSON.parse(data)` above it